# While implementing GeoLocation in Ionic cordova with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic3

I am getting below issue

> [Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys)

[image]

```js
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}

 /*( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-34.397) ) * cos( radians( sa.lat ) ) * cos( radians( sa.lng ) - radians(:lng) ) 
       sin( radians(-34.397) ) * sin( radians( sa.lat ) ) ) ) < :distance */
        }); 
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        });
      }

      function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

```css
#map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
```

```html
</script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
    
    
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: `The script element that loads the API has no API key. Please make sure you include a valid API key as a key parameter. You can generate a new API key on the Google API Console.` Do you have generated an API key? if yes, you should include that in your call to maps api.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is self-descriptive. Just click the link and it will redirect you the following message:

> The script element that loads the API has no API key. Please make sure you include a valid API key as a key parameter. You can generate a new API key on the Google API Console.

Also it provides link to guide about [Obtaining an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

In short, you will need API key from google to run this code. Since you don't have this for now hence you are getting the warning.